# Python Popen hangs, yet same command in Windows cmd window runs fine

Tags: python, cmd

I am pulling my hair out here.  I am spawning a process which I need the feedback from in Python.

When I run the command in the cmd window it runs fine, but when I try to run it via Python the terminal hangs.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(startcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = p.communicate()
```

Where `startcmd` is a string which when printed in the Python console looks like this:

```
"C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 7.2.1/grass72.bat" --version
```

If I copy and paste this into a Windows cmd, it shows the version information and returns control to the command prompt about a second later, but in Python it freezes up.

I should point out, if I replace the `startcmd` string with something like `"dir"` or even `"python --version"`, it works fine!

**Additional:** I have tried `shell=True`, this has the same result.

**Additional:** I have tried sending the cmd and arguments through as an array as suggested in an answer below given that `shell=False`, but this also hangs the same.

**Additional:** I have added the GRASS path to the system PATH, so that now I can simply call `grass72 --version` in the cmd window to get a result, however this also still freezes in Python but works fine in cmd.

**Additional:** I have created a basic .bat file to test if .bat files run ok via Python, here is what I created:

```
@echo off
title Test Batch Script
echo I should see this message
```

This runs fine both in cmd, and in Python.

***Problem found but not solved!***

So, I'm running the script which spawns the process using `subprocess.Popen` using Python 3.6.  The .bat file which is spawned launches a Python script using a version of Python (based on 2.7) which comes shipped with GRASS:

```
%GRASS_PYTHON% "\BLAH\BLAH\grass72.py"
```

What is interesting, is that if I launch the `subprocess.Popen` script with Python 2.7, it works fine.  Ahah, you may think, solved!  But this doesn't solve my problem - because I really need Python 3.6 to be launching the process, also why does it matter what version of Python launches the batch file?  The new Python script which is spawned is launched with Python 2.7 anyway.

Since I started re-directing stdout I can see that there is an error when I use Python 3.6 to launch the process:

```
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Notice its reverting to Anaconda3!  Even though it is launched using python.exe from 2.7!

Comment: Does the command you're running produce a lot of output? There's a limit to how much text a `subprocess.PIPE` can hold, and if it's full it'll block the process.

Comment: No, it creates a lot less than dir does.  It is only a single line.

Comment: What if you replace `startcmd` with `cmd.exe /c "C:\\Program Files\\GRASS GIS 7.2.1\\grass72.bat" --version`?

Comment: BTW, it would be useful if you did some basic debugging to determine: 1. Whether the behavior you're observing is specific to `grass72.bat` or if a simple `.bat` script that prints output exhibits the same behavior.  If specific to `grass72.bat`, then try to isolate why. 2. Whether using `subprocess.PIPE` matters.

Comment: I am actually in the process of looking into that at the moment thanks.  First i'll try your suggestion then get back.

Comment: I have removed path from the problem by adding grass72 as an environment variable, and I have tested a .bat file I created myself and that runs fine.  Leaving the question still hovering -> why does grass72.bat run find in cmd, but not via Python?

Comment: The grass72.bat file actually launches a grass72.py file as it happens, could it be something to do with that?  There is a 1 second delay in the output appearing when using cmd, could the delay be causing the issue, I'm now completely stuck.

Comment: What happened when you tried adding `cmd.exe /c` to `startcmd` as I suggested earlier?

Comment: Same result I'm afraid locks up owing to GRASS trying to pull the Python library from Anaconda if running Python 3.6.  I've created a Python 2.7 install and will run this code using Python 2.7, I have already converted it... but the mystery remains.  Why does the first Python version matter in a Python  -> Batch -> Python chain.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue with Python 3.6 and 3.7 on Windows hanging for subprocess calls:

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(startcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = p.communicate()
```

Upon closer investigation I noticed this occurs only if the process **writes more than about 4 KB (4096 bytes)** of output which might explain why your short script does not reproduce this.

A workaround I found is using `tempfile` in the standard library:

```py
# Write to a temporary file because pipe redirection seems broken
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w+") as tmp_out,
        tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w+") as tmp_err:

    p = subprocess.Popen(startcmd, stdout=tmp_out, stderr=tmp_err,
        universal_newlines=True)

    # `run` waits for command to complete, `Popen` continues Python program
    while p.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(.1)

    # Cursor is after the last write call, reset to read output
    tmp_out.seek(0)
    tmp_err.seek(0)
    out = tmp_out.read()
    err = tmp_err.read()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Was having trouble with my setup.py on Windows 10 and this seems to fix it. (Amazed that you posted this today and I needed it today!!)

Comment: Also, I found that it is advisable to use `communicate()`. With the above fix of using tempfile, it works without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify `shell=True` in your arguments to `Popen`. The recommended usage in that case is to specify a sequence of arguments instead of a string. So you should set `startcmd` equal to `["C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 7.2.1/grass72.bat", "--version"]`.

Comment: I have tried this just now, same result I'm afraid, it hangs.  Same as if I use shell=True which I have tried.  Its so weird how it works in the cmd prompt fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(startcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: Already tried thanks, shell=True is a bad idea apparently anyway.